# Me sale error al guardar imagen: A generic error occurred in GDI+. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, imagen

Resulta que estoy tratando de guardar una imagen en mi computador, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    private static void StartBrowser(string source)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=
                webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser.DocumentText = source;
            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    static void
        webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(
        object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        using (Bitmap bitmap =
            new Bitmap(
                webBrowser.Width,
                webBrowser.Height))
        {
            webBrowser
                .DrawToBitmap(
                bitmap,
                new System.Drawing
                    .Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));


            bitmap.Save(@"c:\imagen.png",
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source = @"
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>An image from W3Schools:</p>
            <img 
                src=""http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"" 
                alt=""W3Schools.com"" 
                width=""104"" 
                height=""142"">
        </body>
    </html>";
        StartBrowser(source);
    }
```

El error me sale justo esta parte:

```
bitmap.Save(@"c:\imagen.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Espero poder contar con su ayuda.

Comment: Tal vez no tienes permisos para escribir directamente en el root del drive C:. Prueba guardando en un subfolder existente: `"@c:\directorio\imagen.png"`.

Comment: Efectivamente,el problema tiene pinta de ser de permisos como comenta @sstan. Utiliza otra carpeta que no tenga permisos restringidos o, para confirmar que el problema es ese, arranca el Visual Studio como Administrador y debería funcionarte

Comment: Exactamente,era esa la causa. Muchas gracias

Comment: @sstan tal vez deberías poner tu comentario como solución, es un fallo habitual :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, el problema es que no tienes tienes los permisos necesarios para escribir directamente en el drive `C:\`: `c:\imagen.png`.

La solución es de cambiar el path a un directorio al que sí tengas acceso en escritura.