# Error genérico de GDI+

Tags: vb6

Muy buenos días.

Tengo un error que se me está generando al querer guardar una imagen usando visual basic 6.

Esta es una aplicación en donde yo le doy la ruta para guardar una serie de archivos, pero al tomar la ruta para guardar la imagen se cae.

[image]

En la ventana yo cargo mi archivo y la carpeta por defecto que tiene por destino es "C:\RenegPagares", al presionar el botón "Generar Seleccionados" la parte del código que se ejecuta para generar la imagen que necesito es:

```
Dim rutCodigoDeBarra As Image = GeneraCodigoBarra(textoCodigoBarra)
Dim archivoCidigoBarras As String = rutaSalida + Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "\CodigoBarra\" + "codigobarras_" + rut.PadLef(9,"0") + "_" + operacionOri + "png"

If System.IO.File.Exist(archivoCodigoBarras) Then
    System.IO.File.Detele(archivoCodigoBarras)
End If

Dim rutCodigoDeBarra.Save(archivoCodigoBarras, Sistem.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

El código de GeneraCodigoBarra es:

```
Private Function GeneraCodigoBarra(ByVal rutCliente As String) As Image

   Dim imagenCodigoBarra As Image
   imagenCodigoBarra = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(rutcliente, 1, True)
   Return imagenCodigoBarra
End Function
```

Dentro de lo que estuve buscando en google llegué a: [link 1](https://geeks.ms/jalarcon/2010/10/18/solucin-al-mensaje-error-genrico-de-gdi-en-aplicaciones-web-que-generan-grficos/) , [link 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122224/me-sale-error-al-guardar-imagen-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-c).

Agregado además que en esta ruta por defecto que estoy poniendo el programa no tiene ningún problema para guardar los archivos que genero y la imagen.

Pero si la cambio a, por ejemplo, una carpeta del escritorio, ahí es cuando me da el error.

Agrego una imagen de la ruta que se genera al mandar a guardar a una carpeta del escritorio:

[image: imagen 2]

la ruta es:

C:\Users\smiranda.apiux\Desktop\CAPTURAS\20210816\CodigoBarra\codigobarras_rutcliente_131.png

Si a alguien le a pasado algo similar o me puede indicar en donde está mi error se lo agradecería mucho.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final el error es por acceso a la carpeta de destino, lo que tuve que hacer para mi caso es en el if en donde pregunto si este archivo existe, en caso contrario que me cree la carpeta para poder guardar el archivo:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(archivoCodigoBarras) Then
   System.IO.File.Delete(archivoCodigoBarras)
Else
   My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaGuardadoCodigoBarras)
End If

rutCodigoBarra.Save(archivoCodigoBarras, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso obtuve ese error porque estaba tratando de guardar una imagen en el mismo archivo que hacía referencia un PictureBox (.ImageLocation y luego .Load) pero usando .Dispose() antes de guardar la imagen se corrigió. Gracias.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).